# How can I combine multiple overlapping UIImages into one UIImage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am creating an app where users can choose from a collection of images (multiple) and add the chosen image to a chosen background. They should then be able to save the image, so I need help merging all the images into one to be saved.

The ViewController has a large UIImageView which serves as the background. When the user selects an image to add, the image is added to the UIImageView as a subview.

```
//chosenImage is a UIImageView with an chosen image
backgroundImageView.addSubView(chosenImage)
```

I need to save the image as the size of the backgroundView with the overlaid images.

How can I achieve this?

I have searched around but only found Obj-C answers and some that don't work.

**For those looking for the same answer this is what you do to save the image on button press:**

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let snapShot:UIView = backgroundImage.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.bounds.size)

    snapShot.drawViewHierarchyInRect(backgroundImage.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to save the image as the size of the backgroundView with the overlaid images.

You have two choices. One is to draw a composite image in code, just drawing the images, positioned as they are by the image view and its subviews, into an image graphics context. In your case, though, a simpler approach would be simply to *render* or *snapshot* the image view: that will effectively be a screen shot of the image view and its subviews, which is exactly what the user is seeing.

Comment: Okay, awesome. So how can I render or snapshot the image view? These are new ideas to me.

Comment: Go to UIView class reference and look at the section called Capturing a View Snapshot.

Comment: Okay, easy enough. Is it possible to then convert the UIView that is returned to an image in order to be saved to the camera roll? I don't need any detail on saving, just verifying I will be able to use what is returned.

Comment: If you render the image view, you render it into a context. Render it into an an image context and now you have a UIImage.